# Is there any way to understand if a raw binary firmware is Cortex-M or not?

Tags: assembly, arm, embedded, reverse-engineering, cortex-m

I have a list of firmwares, and I should filter just the Cortex-M type. Is there any automated way that I can distinguish them from other ARM firmwares?

I have some ideas like Interrupt vector Table (ivt) or looking for other specific features of Cortex-M like Systick, but I am not sure if they are going to work.

Comment: define binary. binary files come in many forms (same firmware can be stored in many different formats).   cortex-m or not of course would be all thumb instructions, but even a specific cortex-m core can be in many different vendor chips and most of the code has to do with the peripherals for that chip.

Comment: cortex-ms have vector tables vs other cores

Comment: what is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: which cortex-m since there are different, incompatible, ones

Comment: @old_timer I have given some firmwares which I can assume they are for ARM devices. But they are raw binary files, not sth like ELF files. I just need to filter Cortex-M firmware. I don't care about the vendor or the chip. I am looking for a way to distinguish Cortex-M firmware from others like Cortex-A. Also, I am looking for any M type, so there is no difference between Cortex-M55 or Cortex-M0+.

Comment: You need to find the differences in the instruction sets and/or standard structures like vector tables or memory sections. Then check for these attributes. You might need to use a disassembler, but then try to find a library, or a tool that can be scripted.

Comment: Try running them ;)!  On a more serious note, I would go back to where you got them and get the provenance, or start over with binaries that have the needed metadata.

Comment: @eftekhar  I think what old timer is trying to say is a binary file could be anything internally. it isn't necessarily a dump of the memory as seen by the MCU.  It might be obfuscated, or encrypted, or in a series of boot commands to populate memory, or hex64 encoded, or...or...you can make some assumptions and start trying to reverse engineer, but until you understand the format of the binary file, you're basically asking the unanswerable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can probably determine heuristically with some degree of reliability:

Raw and complete (i.e. full linked/bootable) Cortex-M images have the vector table at the start.  The vector table is distinguished on Cortex-M by starting with an initial stack-pointer which will necessarily be a RAM address somewhat greater than the minimum, followed by the initial program-counter address (reset vector) which will be a ROM address (on some parts that will be in Flash or it may be an internal mask ROM bootloader).

Further, the value at the address referenced by the reset vector will necessarily be a valid instruction.  If all these images were built by the same tool-chain with the same runtime-start up, they will contain the same code here (but with differing branch address operands), which you may be able to use as a signature. Otherwise testing for a valid instruction is complex without fully decoding/disassembling it.

With that information you might have something like;

```
bool isCortexM( uint32_t* image, uint32_t image_length )
{
    bool is_cortex_m = false ;

    uint32_t sp = image[0] ;
    if( sp > 0x20000000u + MIN_STACK_SIZE && 
        sp < 0x40000000u )
    {
        uint32_t pc = image[1] && 0x00FFFFFFu ;
        if( pc > MIN_VECTOR_TABLE_SIZE && 
            pc < 0x20000000u &&
            pc < image_length )
        {
            instruction = image[pc] ;
            is_cortex_m = instruction != 0 && instruction != 0xFFFFFFFFu ;
        }
    }

    return is_cortex_m ;
}
```

The expression:

```
uint32_t pc = image[1] && 0x00FFFFFFu ;
```

is because often on Flash memory parts the Flash starts at a higher address - 0x08000000 on STM32 for example, and although it is usually aliased at 0x00000000 for reset purposes, the linker will generate addresses relative to the flash start address (because the memory at 0x00000000 may be re-mappable to RAM or on-chip boot ROM for example). The mask ensures indexes relative to zero rather than the start of the code space.

The expression:

```
is_cortex_m = instruction != 0 && instruction != 0xFFFFFFFFu ;
```

is a moderate attempt to exclude common "filler" values that are invalid instructions - it will not determine if the value is truly a valid instruction, but to get there it has to have already passed the first two tests.

`MIN_STACK_SIZE` is somewhat arbitrary, but a minimum viable stack for code that does anything useful might be 256 (0x100) bytes.  If you are uncertain, you could use zero - some run-time start-ups set the SP in any case even though the hardware can do it for you and in that case it may not be set to anything useful in the table - but that would be unusual and ill-advised.

`MIN_VECTOR_TABLE_SIZE` should be at least 0x40 (the core vectors).  The actual size is variable across vendor implementations to support peripheral interrupts.

It is not a fool-proof method - but it implements what I would do manually if inspecting a hex-dump of the image in order to "guess" that it is plausibly a Cortex-M image.

[image]

If you do not need to automate this process, you would do well to either run the code through a disassembly or load it into an instruction-set simulator and see if it runs.

Comment: I used the code that you have written, but some of the firmwares which I know are Cortex-M don't pass the test. For example, I have many Cortex-M firmwares whose PC value is greater than image_length. Also, there are some images in which their sp is sth less than 0x20000000. Is there sth like an offset register that I should consider also?

Comment: @eftekhar - OK, so it needs some tweaks.  It is a strange request, don't expect anyone to tell you how to do it because probably only you in the world have this requirement.  Most people know what their code was built for!  All you can expect here is ideas.  As I mentioned the memory organisation on any particular MCU is not entirely defined by the Cortex-M core.  There are many variations.  I had kind of assumes that you might only be building for one implementation.  For the PC value to be larger than the image, the image must start at some offset (above a bootloader for example).

Comment: You may have to consider all possible architectures and test for them all and see is any _one_ passes.

Comment: It seems to me that knowing if it is Cortex-M or not serves no purpose if the images target different Cortex-M MCUs.  You have to know what the target is to be able to run it, so what purpose does this effort serve?